# Gnome 3 keyboard layout rotation

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ibus

I have Gnome3 and two keyboard layouts (English and Russian) installed.

When I try to switch between these layouts, I am able to switch with Alt-Shift to the Russian layout, but not back to the English one.

It can be done only by selecting the English layout on upper gnome panel.

How can i configure layout rotation (en->ru, ru->en)?